# Custom Spinner to show a photo and a name per line

Tags: android, spinner

I have the following challenge. I need to show a list of people including their photo and name in a dropdown box, so that one person can be selected for further processing by the application. It seems that the Spinner is the appropriate widget for implementing what I need. From the post [Android Bind Spinner to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467464/android-bind-spinner-to-class) I understand I need to implement a custom ArrayAdapter, but I am fairly new to Android and haven't been able to find a good tutorial or explanation that shows me how to do it. 
I would appreciate if you could share some sample code that implements a custom ArrayAdapter or a suggestion if there is another simpler way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I found a tutorial which has the information I needed at [Custom ArrayAdapter for Spinner, with different icons](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html). Hope this helps others as well.